"Vote as duplicate" remains available even after I "Vote[d] as off-topic", but then it fails at the last step of voting
I just voted a non-programming question as off-topic but when I looked up the resolution I realized that the target, while also being off-topic, is available on Stack Overflow, so I wen't back to the review item, to at least leave a link with the duplicate target. To my surprise the "Vote as duplicate" option was still available:

When I tried to use it, everything works, but on the last step instead of casting the vote, it correctly errors with:

I think the "Vote as duplicate" option should also be greyed out along with "Vote as off-topic" when any vote has been cast.

Well, the whole 'Vote as duplicate' Option/Workflow is a bit "flawed", it should be possible to retract a 'Vote as duplicate', which I once did (or tried to do) for this SG Question (deleted since by the Asker) by deleting the Canned Comment about the Dupe, but the Question remained as "Vote as duplicate (1)" (the "(1)" being from me) and still shows as "Vote as duplicate" in my own SG Reviews.
